# How to ignore single test in testKit

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit, testkit

I have a series of tests in the same class all testing the same feature , how can I skip/ignore a single one e.g:

```
class FooTest(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system)
with ImplicitSender
with WordSpecLike
with Matchers
{
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("TESTActorSystem"))

  "Service " should {
     "test something" in {
        OK
      }
    }
     "test to be ignored " in{
      "Not implemented" //ignore this test
      }
}
```

I did use `registerIgnoredTest("test to be ignored")` but I have to remove the `in`. Is there more elegant solution ? like annotation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `WordSpecLike`. In `WordSpecLike`, to ignore a test, you should change `in` into `ignore` like `"test to be ignored " ignore {...`.

Different spec has different way to do it. If you were using `FlatSpec`, you could have annotated the with `ignore should` like `ignore should "test to be ignored " in {...`.

You can see `scalatest` [tagging](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) section for more details.